# arXiv Submission Disappeared

Tags: arxiv

I recently submitted a preprint to arXiv. This is my first time submitting to arXiv. According to https://arxiv.org/help/submit#availability, based on my submission time, the paper should have been announced on Wednesday 20:00 EST (which just passed). At that time, my submission disappeared from my arXiv portal. Is this common? Was it removed due to an error of mine? Up until the announce time, the status showed `Submitted`. It wasn't put on hold, so I assumed there wasn't any errors.

Comment: Arxiv is sometimes weird around holidays. I'd wait at least another 24 hours before worrying about anything.

Comment: Weird as in how? According to this website https://arxiv.org/new/, it should have been posted, right? What could be the reason for the submission disappearing? Should I resubmit the same paper again after 24 hrs? I know that they discourage this.

Comment: Nevermind... Spoke to soon. I see it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give it more time to be published, the system sometimes may not do things strictly on time.